# Why do pro players make these little sidesteps when fighting creeps?

Tags: dota-2

Pro players always make these little circular steps when fighting creeps. Why is that?

Comment: can you provide a screenshot/video/link demonstrating what you are talking about?

Comment: Its probably related to faking out the enemy/getting into the perfect position to last hit.

Answer (score 9):

Honestly, this has nothing to do with auto attack on or off. Or standing still for that matter. You can be constantly moving, but not be applying the side step or animation canceling technique.

There are 2 main reasons why would you would do this side stepping as you would call it.

In both Dota and Dota 2, there is a mechanic called animation canceling. When your hero attacks a unit, the damage gets inflicted upon the unit before the animation is finished. So by side stepping really quickly, and then attacking again, you are able to cancel the ending of your first attack animation and then proceed to initiate another attack animation. This is widely used in the jungle as it increases the number of attacks you can deliver in a specific period of time.

Another reason to do this side stepping is positioning. For example, let's say you are on radiant side, and at the bottom of a creep wave. But perhaps you want to be north of the creep wave and take an offensive position, while pushing the wave. The most efficient way to keep the pushing at a maximum is to hit a creep, animation cancel by taking a step forward and repeat.

EDIT: For melee heros, you side step after the damage is inflicted. For ranged heros, you side step after the projectile is released.

Comment: My guess is also animation canceling

Comment: Can you provide a source for the claim that it would inrease the frequency of attacks? Everything recent I find says otherwise, i.e: http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Attack_animation and various reddit posts.

Comment: That article is in fact true. Cancelling your animation will not allow you to attack faster. Your attacks will always be the same speed. However the number of attacks you produce in a given time increases when you animation cancel. As for a Dota2 reference, I can't find any off a quick google search. All I can say is experiment this in game. The dotacinema video about animation cancelling is actually wrong because their reaction to drow's projectile is slightly delayed. With that said, a lot of advance mechanics are not written about on the dota2 wiki. I can list many that arent written

Comment: If you really want to learn advanced mechanics, check out places on playdota. Like this http://www.playdota.com/forums/showthread.php?t=846936

Comment: "This is widely used in the jungle as it increases the number of attacks you can deliver in a specific period of time." ... Sorry, this is just not true. You can cancel the cosmetic backswing, which allows you to move a further distance between attacks, but you can't attack any faster.

Comment: I don't know if there is some sort of common misunderstanding, but attacking faster is different from increasing the number of attacks over a given time. Attacks will always have the same speed; the difference is you cancel the ending animation of your attack so you can do something else during that time. I've already provided a source that says it increases # of attacks over time within certain conditions.

Comment: If a source isn't enough, I've played over 3000 games of Dota2. I used to be a competitive player and played with the top pros in today's scene. I'm not just making up random facts. There are a lot of advanced mechanics that are simply unwritten and people don't learn about them unless they see someone else do it or are told about it. Just because something isn't written in a formal guide doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: "I've already provided a source that says it increases # of attacks over time within certain conditions" This is entirely different from the other two things you've said, specifically: "However the number of attacks you produce in a given time increases when you animation cancel." and "This is widely used in the jungle as it increases the number of attacks you can deliver in a specific period of time."

Comment: Yes, of course animation canceling can give you an advantage when orb walking or by canceling the cosmetic backswing while chasing, but that is not at all what this question is about- it's about killing creeps when farming.

Comment: I believe you are trying to say that animation cancelling will reduce the idle time between attacks, which I believe is false. I've never heard this to be true before and the dota2 wiki page states the opposite: "For example, if a unit has an attack time of one second, an attack point of 0.3 seconds, and an attack backswing of 0.5 seconds, they will be idle for 0.2 seconds during every attack cycle. Even if the backswing is cancelled after 0.2 seconds, the idle period is extended to 0.5 seconds. However, during that idle period, other commands can be issued such as moving or casting spells."

Comment: @Stuart You can simply test the reduction idle time by shift queueing a combination of attacks. For example, shift queue your hero attacking 3 different neutral camps.

Comment: @krikara You said "This is widely used in the jungle as it increases the number of attacks you can deliver in a specific period of time.", which is contradictory to what the DotA 2 wiki states. You should either remove your sentence from your post or prove that it is true.

Comment: @Stuart It's not false. I've tried explaining it to Decency above, but let me try again. Let's say you are moving from one camp to another. By side stepping after each attack, you maximize your efficiency as opposed to waiting for the ending animations before moving. You're not attacking faster at all and I've never said this. You increase the number of attacks over a period of time by cancelling the end animation and using this time to move.

Comment: @krikara I understand now. The way you originally phrased it was confusing and when you said "I've already provided a source that says it increases # of attacks over time within certain conditions." it further confused me since your link didn't talk about the same thing we're talking about. Thanks for taking the time to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Most of pro players have "auto-attack" option turned on,meaning if they don't move they will attack enemy creep...which they don't want to do unless it is the killing blow.

Some people just stand near creep they want to last hit and keep pressing the stop button until creep HP falls in the last hit zone...but by doing this they are revealing their intentions to the enemy.

On the other side all those micro moves and changes of position are really annoying and confusing to the eye making it harder for your enemy to focus lasthitting/denying.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Dota 2: why would they not want to attack a creep unless it's going to be the last hit?

Comment: @BitLion You should ask that in a separate question, it's a good one and I'd rather not write a really long response in the comments here.

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly just a rhythmic thing. Your hero's attack speed increases as the game goes on and agility/attack speed increases, which changes the attack point of your character. By constantly cancelling the cosmetic backswing of an attack animation, they can know more accurately how long an attack will take. This is crucial during teamfights for heroes who rely on their autoattack and is not something you want to have to think about.

When farming creeps, players also want to minimize the amount of time that they're close to the creep wave, as that's the most exposed a hero should be when farming. By darting in for the last hit and then immediately pulling back, they minimize vulnerability while staying mobile and unpredictable, which is a big help against most skill-based initiation abilities.

Answer (score 0):

I know of three probable reasons for this:

- **Avoid standing still**. You never know what the enemy might be planning and if you're always on the move they will have a harder time initiating properly on you.
- **Moving closer to the next target** while maximizing attack time.
- Simply to "keep on your toes" and **not lose focus**.

There is also a common misconception that moving slightly between each attack would actually let you attack more frequently, by canceling part of the backswing animation. This has to my understanding been proven false in Dota 2.

Comment: I know that in DotA it was the case, but isn't this also a means to also prevent you from auto-attacking creeps? Certainly, there are ways to avoid auto-attacking without moving, but since the other benefits like dodginess and positioning are also prevalent, it's just better to use this as a means.

Comment: @GraceNote You're probably right. I don't know how many pro players have auto-attack on, but for those who do I can see how moving might be a better option than spamming stop command.

Comment: Considering auto-attack is on by default, I would assume most people have it on.

Comment: Most Mids and Carries have auto attack on simply because it is the best way to last hit. Your hero constantly produces the beginning animation of his attack , so when you stop pressing stop, the attack will be substantially faster than having auto attack off and right clicking a creep. Supports and offlaners may turn auto attack off because they don't want to be autoattacking creeps or heros when they don't mean to. This prevents them from pushing the lane, drawing unnecessary aggro, and giving away their position.

Answer (score 0):

Pro players' goal is to get as much money as possible while minimizing risks. Usually this is done by farming while *not* pushing the fight on the lane to the enemy turret. The easiest way to do this is to hit the enemy creep right before they die, so you get the *last* hit and the money that comes with it.

There are two ways to focus on last hitting:

- Move around a lot, smaller steps allow faster reaction time, because it keeps the cursor close to the hero on the screen.
- Use the stop (default <kbd>S</kbd>) action, which keeps the hero stationary and inactive.

Staying completely stationary usually makes it easier for the enemies to come up with their evil plans, so it's a good idea to stay on the move. This is why the first option is generally used.